# How to initialize this array filled with &functionA, &functionB?

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, gcc, avr

I'm busy initializing this array:

```
int menuNumber2FunctionDbase[]= { &functionA , &functionB , &functionC };
```

But it gives: near initialization for menuNumber2FunctionDbase
and:  initialization from incompatible pointer type

I've tried `int*` and `functionA` instead of `&functionA`

What do i do wrong?

Comment: And what is `functionA`? Pointer to the function returning `int`?

Comment: Well I don't know what `&functionA` is, but it's obviously not an `int`. You need to give tell us what functionA is, and also what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: FunctionA is initialized as : void functionA (void) { some_test_code};   It probably has to do with the void of the called function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `functionA` (`B`, `C`) is function that returns `int` and takes no arguments, you need to declare your array to have a valid type:

```
 int (*menuNumber2FunctionDbase[])()  = { functionA, functionB, functionC };
```

You can call `functionB` like this:

```
 std::cout << menuNumber2FunctionDbase[1]() << std::endl;
```

Also, as dmitri suggested, you could define your array type:

```
 typedef int (*int_funct)();
 int_funct menuNumber2FunctionDbase[] = { functionA, functionB, functionC };
```

**EDIT**

As your `functieA` (`B`, `C`) are functions that returns no value, and takes no arguments, typedef should be like this:

```
typedef void (*void_funct)(void);
void_funct menuNumber2FunctionDbase[] = { functionA, functionB, functionC };
```

Without using `typedef`, array declaration should be:

```
void (*menuNumber2FunctionDbase[])(void)  = { functionA, functionB, functionC };
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use typedef in your answer: `typedef int (*funct)(parameters);` This is for better readability...

Comment: I will add that note, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! You guys are great!

What I've changed is: `void (*menuNumber2FunctionDbase[])() = { functieA , functieB , functieC };`

Your other option with typdef is also nice but gives : `(near initialization for 'menuNumber2FunctionDbase[2]')` as an warning

Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should just accept his answer, not post a duplicate of your own.

Comment: Don't quite understand; I'm complimenting you guys for the help and insights. Then showing that I've implemented his solution and how. Could be helpful for others. How is that a duplicate?

Comment: You can do that by commenting on the answer that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), then you can use not only global free-standing functions, but also C++11 lambdas or (with the help of [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) member functions.

```
std::function<void()> menuNumber2FunctionDbase[] = {
    functieA, functieB, functieC
};
```

Comment: Don't know if that would work: working on Eclipse Keppler for AVR atmega644 mcu's...